# Flask API: what's the best way to handle exceptions?

Tags: flask, exception

I'm building a very simple "to-do" API which only has 3 files: a controller with all the endpoints, a service with some logic to manipulate data and a DAO for DB access. So whenever an endpoint gets a request, it calls a method from the service and this method calls a DAO method to interact with the DB.

For example, the service has an `add_item` method which converts a field ("status") into an enum value, and a `KeyError` occurs when the value is something else. So my method goes something like this (*self.dao* is an instance of the DAO class and *ValidStatus* is the enum):

```
def add_item(self, name: str, status: str) -> int:
    valid_status = ValidStatus[status.upper()]
    inserted_id = self.dao.insert(item_name=name, item_status=valid_status)
    return inserted_id
```

Since I'm now trying to handle exceptions, I modified the method to add a try-except block:

```
def add_item(self, name: str, status: str) -> Union[int, str]:
    try:
        valid_status = ValidStatus[status.upper()]
        inserted_id = self.dao.insert_task(item_name=name, item_status=valid_status)
        return inserted_id
    except KeyError as e:
        return (f"{e} status is not valid. Please enter {ValidStatus.TODO} or {ValidStatus.COMPLETED}.")
```

But I'm not sure this is a good approach, since now the method returns 2 different value types: the id of the new item if everthing is ok, or a string with the error message if the exception occurs. And I'm not sure that's the best choice, consistency-wise (and because all my type hinting would get messed up with Unions).

I thought another option would be to always return a tuple with a dict to create a json formatted response and an http code. So when everything goes well it would be something like `return {"new item id": inserted_id}, 200` and when there's an exception it would be something like
`return {"error": "Something went wrong"}, 400`. But I'm not sure this is a good approach either, since then the service would be dealing with http status codes and json structured dicts, and that sounds more like a controller's responsibility.

So is there an advised best practice for this?

Comment: Ok, someone voted down and didn't even say why. But in SO there's always people to point out that your question is dumb.

Answer (score 1):

Well, generally speaking, there are two types of errors to handle, one is user input-related errors, such as the status key error in your case, which usually return 4xx, and the other is server-side processing errors, such as database errors, which usually return 5xx.

For the first type of error, we often use some kind of validator, such as [marshmallow](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), and handle those errors in the controller. For example,

```
@bp.route("", methods=["POST"])
@login_required
def new_paper():
    req = request.json
    try:
        cleaned_data = CreateUpdatePaperSchema(unknown=EXCLUDE).load(req)
    except ValidationError as err:
        return err_response(err_msg=fmt_validate_err(err), status_code=400)
```

For the second type of error, we often use a global exception catching mechanism to handle that uniformly. For example,

```
@app.errorhandler(Exception)
def handle_exception(exc):
    db.session.rollback()

    app.logger.error(exc, exc_info=True)
    err_msg = "Something went wrong"
    return err_response(err_msg=err_msg, status_code=500)
```

Comment: Thanks! This looks like a nice alternative. I'm only left thinking if I shouldn't handle exceptions at the service level at all, or if there's some case where that would be advisable.

Comment: If it were me, I would not deal with these exceptions at first. If later, there is a need to return more detailed and domain specific error messages, then I would handle some exceptions for some services.